# Change the size of spaces between words in TikZ environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, white-space

I tried to change size of spaces between all words (inter word spacing) in a TikZ node but it seems not working. Anyone knows another approach that could work?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, rectangle, text width=3cm] (a) {This is a ragged right and hyphenated text in TikZ node.};
\node[draw, rectangle, anchor=north west, text width=3cm] at (a.south west) {\fontdimen2\font=0.5ex%
This is a ragged right and hyphenated text in TikZ node.};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: The results]

Comment: It seems tikz uses `\raggedright`.  Try `\parbox{15cm}{\sloppy\lipsum[1]}` instead (no [text width] needed).

Comment: That indeed fixes the spaces but it makes the paragraph justified. If I add `\raggedright` instead of `\sloppy` then the issue is that the paragraph is not hyphenated anymore. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was what you wanted.  What exactly do you want to do with the spaces between words anyway?

Comment: I want a paragraph inside a TikZ node with possibility to adjust the size of inter word spaces. I also need this paragraph to be ragged right and hyphenated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) The package `ragged2e` provides for the situation you want with `\RaggedRight`. It seems that [hyphenation doesn't help too much](https://practicaltypography.com/hyphenation.html) when text is not justified, but of course we are here to answer your question, not dole out internet opinions.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,rectangle] at (0,0) {
  \fontdimen2\font=2em%
  \parbox{3cm}{\RaggedRight This is a ragged right and hyphenated text in a TikZ node.}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: This is indeed what I was hoping to achieve. Thank you so much.