# Font size (via \selectfont) and feature (WordSpace) in TikZ node / group

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, fontspec, fontsize, tikz-node

I'm trying to set the `WordSpace` feature and some appropriate `\fontsize` for text inside a Ti*k*Z node. Below is the expected result (given by the fourth set of code below, outside `tikzpicture`). I've chosen an exaggerated `WordSpace` to make the effect more visible.

[image]

**Case 1)**
Regarding the first two lines, with

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[text width=\paperwidth] at (0,0) {%
    \fontsize{24pt}{36pt}\selectfont%
    Introduction\\to some subjects
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I'm getting

[image]

As you can see, the `WordSpace` setting doesn't work, and the line spacing is incorrect.

**Case 2)**
However, if I add the last line to it, the line spacing becomes normal:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[text width=\paperwidth] at (0,0) {%
    \fontsize{24pt}{36pt}\selectfont%
    Introduction\\to some subjects\\[1.5em]%
    \fontsize{18pt}{27pt}\selectfont%
    with some subtitle
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

The `WordSpace` setting still doesn't work, though.

**Case 3)**
While trying to to understand what is happening here, I also tried to put the text inside a group:

```
{%
\fontsize{24pt}{36pt}\selectfont%
Introduction\\to some subjects\\[1.5em]%
\fontsize{18pt}{27pt}\selectfont%
with some subtitle%
}
```

[image]

which made me even more confused, since here the line spacing is wrong but `WordSpace` setting works.

**Question)**
Why do these happen? And to obtain the desired result within a Ti*k*Z node, what should I do?

---

Below is the complete code.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{SourceSansPro-Regular.otf}
  [
    BoldFont       = SourceSansPro-Semibold.otf ,
    ItalicFont     = SourceSansPro-RegularIt.otf ,
    BoldItalicFont = SourceSansPro-SemiboldIt.otf ,
    WordSpace      = 5 ,
  ]

\begin{document}

% First
\begin{minipage}{.5\paperwidth}
{%
\fontsize{24pt}{36pt}\selectfont%
Introduction\\to some subjects\\[1.5em]%
\fontsize{18pt}{27pt}\selectfont%
with some subtitle%
}
\end{minipage}

% Second
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[text width=\paperwidth] at (0,0) {%
    \fontsize{24pt}{36pt}\selectfont%
    Introduction\\to some subjects
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

% Third
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[text width=\paperwidth] at (0,0) {%
    \fontsize{24pt}{36pt}\selectfont%
    Introduction\\to some subjects\\[1.5em]%
    \fontsize{18pt}{27pt}\selectfont%
    with some subtitle
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

% Fourth
\begin{minipage}{.5\paperwidth}
\fontsize{24pt}{36pt}\selectfont%
Introduction\\to some subjects\\[1.5em]%
\fontsize{18pt}{27pt}\selectfont%
with some subtitle%
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need `\par` after text to make the `\selectfont` active. But I don't know how to make the wordspace working in node.

Comment: @Tom Thank you, that solves half of the problem.

Comment: I found this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506967/change-the-size-of-spaces-between-words-in-tikz-environment, \usepackage{ragged2e} could solve the problem. I don't know the reason behind it.

Comment: @Tom Thank you for this suggestion. I read the code and it seems `ragged2e` sets `\spaceskip\z@`, which (I don't understand but) works here. It almost looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `\spaceskip` is greater than zero, it takes precedence over `WordSpace`, as the following example shows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[WordSpace={10,5,3}]

\begin{document}

Abc def ghi

\spaceskip=1pt

Abc def ghi

\end{document}
```

[image]

It happens that in Ti*k*Z sets the `\spaceskip` in nodes typeset with the `text width` option. Just reset it to zero *and* add a `\par` at the end, which can be `\\`, because Ti*k*Z uses `\raggedright`.

Some notes:

1. in your first `minipage` example you have a pair of braces that causes the standard baselineskip to be used, because the implicit `\par` is after the `}`.
2. `WordSpace=5` is equivalent to `WordSpace{5,5,5}` which is not likely what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setmainfont{SourceSansPro}
  [
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont    = *-Regular,
    BoldFont       = *-Semibold,
    ItalicFont     = *-RegularIt,
    BoldItalicFont = *-SemiboldIt,
    WordSpace      = {5,3,1},
  ]

\begin{document}

\subsection*{First}

\begin{minipage}{.75\textwidth}
\fontsize{24pt}{36pt}\selectfont
Introduction\\to some subjects\\[1.5em]
\fontsize{18pt}{27pt}\selectfont
with some subtitle
\end{minipage}

\subsection*{Second}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[text width=0.75\textwidth] at (0,0) {%
    \fontsize{24pt}{36pt}\selectfont\spaceskip=0pt
    Introduction\\to some subjects\\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\subsection*{Third}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[text width=0.75\textwidth] at (0,0) {%
    \fontsize{24pt}{36pt}\selectfont
    Introduction\\to some subjects\\[1.5em]
    \fontsize{18pt}{27pt}\selectfont
    with some subtitle\\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\subsection*{Fourth}

\begin{minipage}{.75\textwidth}
\fontsize{24pt}{36pt}\selectfont
Introduction\\to some subjects\\[1.5em]
\fontsize{18pt}{27pt}\selectfont
with some subtitle
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can see that in the second example the `WordSpace` is honored, while it isn't in the third one.

Comment: Thank you for the analysis! I have a few confusions though: 1) should I always put a `\par` at the end when using the key `text width`? 2) I don't quite understand the description "*scale the nominal value, the stretch, and the shrink of the interword space*" in the `fontspec` documentation for `WordSpace`. In the real situation I'm using it because the whitespace in the font `SourceSansPro` is too small so I set `WordSpace=1.25`. To mimic your `{5,3,1}`, do you think maybe I should write `{1.25,1.05,1}` (sorry, I don't understand what are the second and third numbers mean)?

Comment: @Jinwen Apparently, Ti*k*Z doesn't add a par at the end of those text nodes. You may use a single factor, but I'm not sure you want to multiply each component by the same factor. Your judgment.