# Does the interword space need to be manually reset in TikZ nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontspec, tikz-node

In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/650233/194994), I learnt that the font feature `WordSpace` does not work inside a Ti*k*Z node. A solution is proposed to use the `ragged2e` package. Having seen its documentation, it seems that what really works is `\spaceskip\z@`, which according to the documentation means "*reset the interword space*".

My question is that, is this supposed to be a bug or is this by design? Should I always add `\spaceskip\z@` to my packages where I put text inside Ti*k*Z nodes?

Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{SourceSansPro-Regular.otf}
  [
    BoldFont       = SourceSansPro-Semibold.otf ,
    ItalicFont     = SourceSansPro-RegularIt.otf ,
    BoldItalicFont = SourceSansPro-SemiboldIt.otf ,
    WordSpace      = 5 ,
  ]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[text width=\paperwidth] at (0,0) {%
    \makeatletter
    \spaceskip\z@
    \makeatother
    \fontsize{24pt}{36pt}\selectfont%
    Some text for demonstration\\Next line
    \par
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\noindent
\fontsize{24pt}{36pt}\selectfont%
Some text for demonstration\\Next line

\end{document}
```

Comment: The Ti*k*Z & PGF manual says that `align=left` (which you have because your node uses `text width`) “uses the original plain TeX definition of a ragged right border”. In plain TeX, `\raggedright` sets `\spaceskip` to .3333em. Non-zero values take precedence over the font-specified normal interword space (TeXbook p. 76).

Comment: See [align=left](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/2b1da75747475e869ef9dd48de271b80bc851be3/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex#L1176) and [text ragged](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/2b1da75747475e869ef9dd48de271b80bc851be3/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex#L1135-L1136) in tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex for the Ti*k*Z code behind `align=left`. You can use `\node[text width=\paperwidth, font=\fontsize{24pt}{36pt}\selectfont, align=flush left] {Some text for demonstration\\Next line};` (no need for `\par`), but the results may differ.

Comment: @frougon Thank you for your explanation and suggestion! I have modified my package to use `align=flush left`, and it worked just fine.